# How to make data in a sharded collection move away from a shard

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded collection with 3 shards (`shard1`, `shard2`, `shard3`). Each shard is a 3-node replicaset (`rs1`, `rs2`, `rs3`).

I have a db called `activity` that has a large sharded collection called `items`. ie( `activity.items`). The data in this collection is split across `shard{1,2,3}`.

I have another db called `app` and collection called `users` (ie, `app.users`). This is not a sharded collection. It is housed on `shard1`.

I want the data from `activity.items` that current resides on `shard1` to no longer reside on shard1.  I don't want any `activity.items` data on `shard1`.. It should either move to `shard2` or `shard3`.  Or if it's easier, I can spin up a `shard4`

Is this possible? Any high level guidance on which commands to be looking at example docs would be greatly appreciated.  I'm open to alternative solutions that achieve my goal of moving the `activity.items` collection data away from `shard1`.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/zone-sharding/#behavior-and-operations

Comment: Thank you, but it's not clear on how to introduce or use zones to accomplish what I want.  Are you suggesting creating some minimal/empty zone on the shard that I don't want any `activity.items` on?

Comment: You can use the `removeShard` command. First, move your user's collections to some other place, and then remove this shard. This will move the item's collection data to other shards. Then you can restore your user's collections, to a new shard. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/removeShard/

Answer (score 0):

You can use moveChunk command.

This old script is used to move everything to one shard (Primary), but you get the idea. In your case, use just filter (for source) only one shard and then for the destination you create "loop" where you distribute those chunks evenly to those other shards. Of course, you can move them to only one shard, and let the balancer to distribute those chunks.

```
database = 'activity'
collection = database + '.items.chunks'
sh.stopBalancer()
use config
primary = db.databases.findOne({_id: database}).primary
// move all chunks to primary
db.chunks.find({ns: collection, shard: {$ne: primary}}).forEach(function(chunk){
   print('moving chunk from', chunk.shard, 'to', primary, '::', tojson(chunk.min), '-->', tojson(chunk.max));
   sh.moveChunk(collection, chunk.min, primary);
});
```

Comment: Would the balancer put the chunks back after it’s restarted?

Comment: Yes, of course... You asked how to move chunks away, but not keep them away. :-)
That latter one is a bit of a problem, as long as you have that shard part of the cluster. But, from the back of my head, tag aware sharding could be the solution.